# Get unique values from spseg() output

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I'm using the package `seg` to get racial segregation values for census tracts in Seattle WA. The function `spseg()` calculates four measures of segregation and the `spplot` function maps the segregation results of each tract at its centroid.

*How can I get a vector for individual tract values created in each point like in the `spplot` output?*

(download for the [Seattle shapefile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2739825/seattle.zip) in question)

```
library(seg)
library(rgdal)

# load data
sea.shp <- readOGR(".","seattle")

# run segregation measure
sea.seg <- spseg(x=sea.shp, data=sea.shp@data[,2:5])
print(sea.seg, digits=3)
as.list(sea.seg)
spplot(sea.seg)
```

The `spseg` output provides four segregation measures for the whole group of tracts. I want to get a vector of the values for each of these tracts. In other words, for each dot in the `spplot`, what are each of those values?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
spplot(as(sea.seg, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")["his2010"])
```

you get individual values e.g. by first converting to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, then to a `data.frame`:

```
x <- as(as(sea.seg, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"), "data.frame")
```

and you get an individual vector from a `data.frame` by

```
x$his2010
```

or, if you shortcut, by

```
as(sea.seg, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")[["his2010"]]
```

other measures are not available in `sea.seg` for each tract, as you can see from the output of

```
`str(sea.seg)`
```

Comment: and what does that do? If it works, how? Please add explanation to your post, to make it more useful to future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: Edzer, thanks so much but this only provides a map of just the hispanic segregation measures. I tried to clarify my question a little more above - how can I get a vector of individual values for each of those dots? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my disappointment, `spplot` is only plotting the actual data from the `sea@data[,2:5]`, which are the proportions of each racial group, NOT the segregation measures calculated by the `spseg` function.

```
# as a visual check, I'll change all the wht2010 proportions to .5
sea.shp@data$wht2010 <- .5
sea.seg <- spseg(x=sea.shp, data=sea.shp@data[,2:5])
spplot(sea.seg)
```

Thanks for the input!